# How to change the content of a default page layout in PHP

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP webpage designed like the layout below. It is saved as `default.php` and is intended to be imported as the page layout for all pages in the website. The content in 'section A' and 'section B' is the same for all pages but I want to change the content of 'section C' for each page. How do I do this?

I know I can use "content place holder" in .NET framework, but how do I do it in PHP? I am new to PHP - your help will be appreciated.

```
+------------------------------+
|        section  A            |
|-----+------------------------|
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
|  B  |     section C          |
|     |                        |
|     |                        |
+-----+------------------------+
```

Comment: How is default.php loaded? Are you using a framework? An accurate answer will depend on these implementation details.

Comment: I use "require_once('default.php')" to load the default page which already has content in 'section c'

Comment: Ok, i';; write an answer. Please make a comment on it if you have any questions

Comment: James Hunt's answer, second example, is closest to .NET framework's "content place holder", of all the answers here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to use a php page as a template, you have a few different methods of approach.

Either seperating your master page into two, one before section C and one after, then including each before/after your page.

Example:

```
include('includes/masterA.php');
//INSERT PHP HERE
echo $content;
include('includes/masterB.php');
```

Or pre-computing your php code into a content variable, telling the master page to echo it and, as the include counts it as one big script, will simply pick up the one you pre-assigned and echo the results.

Example:

```
//INSERT PHP HERE
$content = "textfromphp";
include('includes/master.php');
```

master.php:

```
echo "<div>Section A</div>";
echo "<div>Section B</div>";
echo "<div>Content:".$content."</div>";
```

Comment: The second example is especially good. In practice, each `div` should be given a `class`, so that it can be styled (and even positioned on the page) using `css`. E.g. `<div class="sectionA">...`. Then in .css, `.sectionA { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ob_start" to capture section C content inside one variable
Then inside default.php add it at section C

Section C output

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    echo "<div>Hello</div>";

    $section_c = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    ?>
```

Default.php

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="section-a">...</div>
    <div id="section-b">...</div>
    <div id="section-c">
      <?php echo $section_c ?>
    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

Or, it would be good to use Twig Template Engine, which solve this problem in clean and standard way.
you can find more information on [**Twig**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and installation and configuration guide on **[Twig Installation and Configuration](http://www.zainabed.com/2014/10/twig-tutorials-install-and-configure.html)**

Comment: This isn't a complete example. I think what is missing is on each page, after `ob_end_clean();`, need `include('default.php');`

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, if you are including default.php using require, you simply need to swap the content in default.php for a variable, then set that variable before you require default.php.

As an example:

```
//index.php

$page = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

$pages = ['home','about','contact'];

$include = in_array($page, $pages) ? $page . '.php' : 'error.php';

require_once('default.php');

//default.php

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Page header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="leftcol">
            <p>left column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <?php include($include);?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You would then access the different pages like so:

```
example.com/ //would show homepage
example.com/?p=about //would show about page
example.com/?p=blahfff //would show error page
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the page class, when you get to section C, all you need to do is have a var named content that will be echoed. So the script should load like this:

1. page class
2. section C (regardless of what that section is)

so every thing that you click and anywhere you go, the result must be returned to a method, lets call it `displayContent($content)` that relays in the page class. In other words, the page class needs to be included in every php file that is to be displayed in section C and the `displayContent($content)` method called each time, at the ending of the file, with $content filled with HTML code :D

Hope it helps!

Keep on coding!

Ares.

Comment: IMHO, this answer will be difficult for a beginner to use. Would be much better to show sample code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP `include` function to do this, consider the following example.

default.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><?php include 'sec-a.php';?></header>
        <section>
            <aside><?php include 'sec-b.php';?></aside>
            <aside><?php include 'sec-c.php';?></aside>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

section-a.php:

```
<code>to appear in section A</code>
```

section-b.php:

```
<code>to appear in section B</code>
```

section-c.php:

```
<code>to appear in section C</code>
```

Comment: No, this won't satisfy the requirement.  Given a single default.php, the question is how to have multiple pages, that differ only in section c. In the approach shown here, default.php would have to be copied to each page. That defeats the purpose of default.php, which is a *template* that can be modified, automatically changing all pages.